# How to connect to a relay service hosted on the service bus in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, servicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebusrelay

I want to use Azure service bus in my iOS app to communicate with server i have went through the below link. its pointing to C#.Need suggestions to work on iOS.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-relay/#next_steps

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using `WebHttpRelayBinding` for your service so you can hit the Azure endpoint using HTTP / HTTPS.

Comment: This is a good option, and here is a sample for that:http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Relayed-Messaging-Bindings-a6477ba0

Answer (score 0):

WCF supports both RESTfull and classic SOAP style messaging but using lightweight json requests in a RESTfull service would be better from a mobile app.

read the following article for details. but you don't need to write custom autostarter if you are using IIS 7.5 or greater with appfabric, since it has autostart functionality in built.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh966775.aspx

if you don't need request-response messaging pattern then you can also consider service bus queues for persistence, and your on-premise process can pull and process the messages at its own pace.